# Error al convertir varchar en datetime

Tags: sql-server

Al realizar un insert en una tabla en el campo de fecha inserto un varchar con el siguiente formato
'2021/07/15' pero en sql me lo toma como si lo estuviera metiendo como ydm y aun cuando uso el SET DATEFORMAT YMD al inicio de mi sentencia me sigue fallando el insert con el siguiente error.

La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo

No encuentro otra forma de corregirlo, y no quiero usar el cast as datetime por que el error esta saltando con muchos sp que se tendrian que mover, alguien sabe de alguna solucion mas optima que ir a poner un cast?

el insert seria de la siguiente forma

```
INSERT INTO borrame_T_example
SELECT numero,dato, Fecha --- Suponiendo que fecha retorna '2021/07/15'
FROM Tabla_Data WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Fecha = @Fecha
```

Comment: El formato que funciona independientemente de cómo esté configurado el lenguaje y locale del servidor y del cliente es `yyyymmdd` (sin separadores). Si puedes cambiar tus cadenas a algo como `'20210715'`, esa sería una solución robusta.

Comment: Traté de replicar tu error y no se puede. Creo que el problema es algo distinto.

Answer (score 0):

Traté de replicar el error mediante el siguiente código y no arrojó ningún problema.

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
CREATE TABLE borrame_T_example (Fecha date);

INSERT INTO borrame_T_example
SELECT '2021/07/15';

SELECT * FROM borrame_T_example;
```

Lo más probable es que tengas un problema distinto. Para ello, hice otra prueba que puedes tratar de ajustar para identificar los problemas con tus datos.

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
CREATE TABLE borrame_T_example (id int, Fecha date);

INSERT INTO borrame_T_example SELECT 1, '2021/07/15';
GO
INSERT INTO borrame_T_example SELECT 2, '2021/15/07';
GO
INSERT INTO borrame_T_example SELECT 3, '07/15/2021';
GO
INSERT INTO borrame_T_example SELECT 4, '15/07/2021';
GO
INSERT INTO borrame_T_example SELECT 5, '20210715';
GO
INSERT INTO borrame_T_example SELECT 6, '2021-07-15';
GO
INSERT INTO borrame_T_example SELECT 7, '15072021';
GO

--Los que se convirtieron 
SELECT * FROM borrame_T_example;

--Los que generaron error
SELECT id, cfecha
FROM ( SELECT 1, '2021/07/15'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021/15/07'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, '07/15/2021'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, '15/07/2021'
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, '20210715'
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, '2021-07-15'
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, '15072021')t(id, cfecha)
WHERE TRY_CAST(cfecha AS datetime) IS NULL
GO

DROP TABLE borrame_T_example;
```

Para evitar este tipo de problemas, lo ideal es que siempre se manejen las fechas como fechas y no como texto. En caso de necesitar convertirlas a texto, hay que usar un formato universal como `YYYYMMDD` o `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.mss`

Comment: Si solo que esta parte es un sistema externo del cual yo tomo los datos pero ahora las fechas estan tronando, y no se si es por que se migro la db o por otra cosa y es lo que estoy buscando

Comment: Trata de insertar a una tabla de paso con puro varchar, para poder examinar los datos y ver cuales están generando problemas.

Comment: si, yo creo voy a ver como editar ese string pero pues a ver que pasa por que como te comento son cambios que afectan a muchas tablas